# adding a class name to manipulate the node does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, css-transitions

So basically I want to remove a div element by giving it 0 height value when click another element(anchor) and also I want to give transition: height 4s so it can be animated as it disappears.

i have css as below:

```
.slides > div {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100vh;
     background-image: url('sdfsd.jpg');
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
     transform: scale(1.14, 1.14);
     transition: transform 5000ms;
}

.erase {
    height: 0;
    transition: height 4s;
 }
```

below is the function to give the class name to the element.

```
redirectToHome = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    for(let node of document.querySelectorAll('.slides > div')){
        node.classList.add('erase');
    }
    // console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.slides > div'))
}
```

I can inspect from the browser that the class name is added to the element, but somehow I don't see any css property for the class name. 
* However, modifying visibility works.

```
.erase {
    visibility: hidden;
 }
```

Comment: the `.slides > div` is stronger defined than `.erase`, try .slides > .erase

Comment: still not working..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sa1ge208/11/

Comment: oh yes ! it is working ! thank you Eydrian !!

Comment: okay, posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.slides > div` is stronger defined than just `.erase` and is therefor overruling `.erase`
You need to nest the `.erase` rule as well into `.slides > .erase`

See example below

```
.slides > div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('sdfsd.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    transform: scale(1.14, 1.14);
    transition: transform 5000ms;
}

.slides > .erase {
    height: 0;
    transition: height 4s;
}
```

Example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/sa1ge208/11/

Answer (score 1):

you should describe transition property to parent selector like for .slides > div or in entire document body

Answer (score 1):

`.slides > div` has a higher priority than `.erase`. Therefore the properties of height and transition which you have already defined in the higher priority selector are not going to applied.

You can solve this in the following manner:

```
.erase {
    height: 0 !important;
    transition: height 4s !important;
 }
```